# Managing spill files in greenplum

Tags: database-administration, greenplum

In greenplum, we know the spill files are generated when the memory threshold exceeds, but are these spill files temporary or permanent and how do we get rid of these after our query is over? Is is automatic or we need to remove these files
And what is the size of each spill file

Comment: The files are temporary.

Comment: And how are they deleted? What is the criteria?

Comment: My assumption the files get deleted at the end of the transaction. I've never seen a situation where a long running session with many queries that spill are retaining spill files.